# Bcache writeback_percent max value

Tags: bcache

I'm tryng to set

```
writeback_percent
```

at a value > 40 but it only accept value between 0 and 40.

If i set

```
echo 50 >   /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/writeback_percent
```

then when i read the value

```
more  /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/writeback_percent
```

i have 40.
For value<=40 the settings work fine.

My setting for cache type are

```
more  /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/cache_mode 
writethrough [writeback] writearound none
```

I know this is dangerous but this is not a problem for me.

As far as i understand writeback_percent is the % used from dirty data in cache, why i can't use 90% or 100% of available space?
May be i dont' understand quite well this settings?

Comment: Thank you @sourcedj, but may be i'm wrong but previously i was able to use a value > 40. This are file systems in use only for automatic test purpose so data are copied from a source that is not cached , backupped and so on so no problem if i lost this data. Anyway i understand that probability of data loss increase but i can't find any info about this limit, so i ask here about some clarification. And anyway my English is not perfect :)

Comment: Sorry, I was criticizing only a small detail.  Don't worry about it.  It sounds like I wasn't very helpful!  I don't know why bcache is not accepting a value > 40.  It's a perfectly reasonable question to have, hopefully someone who knows more will see your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hardcoded value in the bcache drive code - linux/drivers/md/bcache/writeback.h. The only way to change this limit is to rebuild the driver from source.

Comment: True, except wrong source file, at least in v4.19.  It's in sysfs.c: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.9/source/drivers/md/bcache/sysfs.c#L267 .  I don't know the relation between the two values.

Comment: in 5.11 I believe it is different, `CUTOFF_WRITEBACK` , `CUTOFF_WRITEBACK_SYNC` `CUTOFF_WRITEBACK_MAX`  `CUTOFF_WRITEBACK_SYNC_MAX`

Answer (score 2):

According to
https://evilpiepirate.org/git/linux-bcache.git/tree/Documentation/bcache.txt
**writeback_percent**
If nonzero, bcache tries to keep around this percentage of the cache dirty by throttling background writeback and using a PD controller to smoothly adjust the rate.

So this is a target objective for the amount of dirty cache. Interpreting the debate below, this objective is met dynamically, while activity continuously occurs. It is probable that with enough time, bcache finishes the write back operation, even at the writeback_rate.

Comment: you are wrong. Data is not at risk since bcache always does persistent write on caching device. And you also wrong with having dirty set to 0% , setting dirty to 0% means caching device would be completely useless or the same as having `writethrough` mode enabled which is meaningless too if you want to take advantage of SSD. Best performance would be achieved by setting writeback_percent to 80% and that can only be done by modifying the kernel module sources

Comment: "why would you": It can speed up processes so much that it pays off even when including the time for making and verifying an additional complete copy of all data.

Comment: @Nulik: The optimal value for `writeback_percentage` depends on the application and hardware. Large gains from increasing the percentage over 40% are possible but usually one also has a lot of read operations and these benefit from cached data regardless of whether the cache is dirty or not.

Comment: @Nulik, maybe I wrongly interpreted the sentence "in writeback mode you'll lose data if something happens to your SSD", but it seems some scenarios with the loss of the caching device cause a permanent loss of data. Now I understand I miss information about how writeback behaves asymptotically, that is with enough time it probably writes all the data back at the writeback_rate speed.

Comment: @JoachimWagner I have hardcoded 90% instead of 40% in the kernel but got no gains in performance because the bottleneck is my SSD, not the bcache module.

Comment: @hjohanns Yes, and, in addition to writeback_rate, about 90 seconds of no activity on the bcache device seems to trigger that the dirty data is flushed to the backing storage at high speed. I haven't seen this documented anywhere but that's what I spotted on a few occasions in my 2 x 3 I/O bandwidth monitor showing separate plots for read and write on bcache device, cache and backing storage.

Comment: @Nulik Thanks reporting back on performance observations. Users not willing to change the kernel can probably detect saturation already by comparing performance with 30% and 40% `writeback_percentage`.